# On calculating sigma algebras generated by specific functions.

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I started (again!) with the intention to build an interesting example of a computation of conditional expectation with respect to $\sigma(X) $ when $X $ is not a step function. My first example, choosing $\Omega = [-1, 1], $ ${\cal F} = {\cal B}(\Omega), $ and $P = (1/2)\lambda $ with 
$X: \Omega \mapsto R: \omega \mapsto \omega^2 $ or $|\omega | $ worked fine, since $\sigma(X) = \{A \in {\cal B}(\Omega): A= -A\}. $
When I tried to have a function that is not symmetric, say 
$Y(\omega) = -\omega\cdot I_{[-1, 0]}(\omega) + 2\omega \cdot I_{[0, 1]}(\omega), $ not such luck. Now, I can see the overall structure of $\sigma(Y), $ but cannot really write it down in an elegant manner: I see that intervals like $(a, b) $ with $a= -1/2*b $ should be part of $\sigma(Y), $ if $b > 0, $ but I was hoping to get an elegant expression like in the case of $\sigma(X) $ above. Is that possible?

Thank you.

Maurice

Comment: $\sigma(Y)=\mathcal{F}$...

Comment: I am not sure if the comment above was an attempt to answer or just some humor...

Comment: Here is the joke: $\{[a,b]:-1\le a<b\le 1\}\subset \sigma(X)$.

Comment: @ d.k.o. I was hoping for an equality more than an inclusion. Something like $\sigma(X) = \{A: {\cal B}(\Omega): .....\}. $

Comment: $\sigma(Y)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$. Isn't the latter elegant enough?

Comment: So, I am asking for I tried for a while now, if that really the very best one can do? No way to characterize $\sigma(Y) $ with a bit more structure like in the case of the $\sigma(X) $ in the examples that I gave earlier?

Comment: Like this: "$\sigma(Y) = \{A \in {\cal B}(\Omega): A=A\}$"?

Comment: OOhhhh.. I see .. my bad... gee... I am a jackass... I meant the function $Y(\omega) = -\omega\cdot I_{[-1.0]}(\omega) + 2\omega\cdot I_{[0, 1/2]}(\omega $  My apologies.

Comment: Yes.. I am hoping that there is some structure for $\sigma(Y) $ that makes it a bit more amenable than just a Borel $\sigma$-algebra.  I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for any $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, 
$$
X^{-1}(B)=X^{-1}(B\cap[0,1])\cup X^{-1}(B\cap(1,2])\equiv C_1\cup C_2.
$$
Notice that $C_1\cap C_2=\emptyset$, $C_2=\emptyset$ or $C_2\subseteq(1/2,1]$ and $C_1$ is "symmetric" around $0$ in the following sense: if $C_1^+\equiv C_1\cap [0,1/2]$ and $C_1^-\equiv C_1\cap [-1,0)$, then $C_1^-=-2C_1^+$.

For an integrable random variable $Y$, the conditional expectation $\mathsf{E}[Y\mid \sigma(X)]=Z(\omega)$, where
\begin{align}
Z(\omega)&:=Y(\omega)1_{(1/2,1]}(\omega)+\frac{Y(\omega)+Y(-2\omega)}{2}1_{[0,1/2]}(\omega)\\
&\quad+\frac{Y(\omega)+Y(-\omega/2)}{2}1_{[-1,0)}(\omega).
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much... Much appreciated... Now I get the structure so that it could be used to condition and guess the form of $E[Y| \sigma(X)].